# How do I structure a custom task and how do I get pretty output?

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I'm writing an a custom task in Capistrano 3 (lib/capistrano/tasks/revision) that is fetching the revision of a running application via curl.

Then it compares the running version with the latest deployed and compares them, if they are not the same an error should be thrown.

I got to the point that the revision of the running application is fetched and compared with an empty string so to throw an error.

The problem I'm having is that the output of this task is not pretty, it's just plain white text.

What am I missing? I've been digging in the documentation all day.

Regards!

revision.rake:

```
namespace :revision do
  desc 'Check revision of all applications to determine if the application is running the latest deployed revison'
  task :check do
    puts 'Checking revision of all supported applications'

    invoke 'revision:httpapi'
  end

  task :httpapi do
    on roles(:httpapi), in: :sequence do |host|
      puts "Checking revision of httpapi on #{host}"
      begin
        response = capture "curl -L 'http://#{fetch(:diagnostics_username)}:#{fetch(:diagnostics_password)}@#{host}/diagnostics/status?mode=extended&output=detailed'"
        object = JSON.parse(response, object_class: OpenStruct)

        unless object.result.revision == "" #For test, just compare to empty string so error is thrown
          raise 'The running revision is not the same as the installed, please restart all applications'
        end
      rescue Exception => e
        raise e.message
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Output:

```
gonace@ubuntu ~/Development/tulo-deployment (master) $ cap test revision:check
Enter a branch or tag name to deploy (defaults to develop)
Please enter branch (develop): 
Deploying branch/tag: develop
rvm 1.28.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
rvm 1.28.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
ruby-1.9.3-p545
ruby-1.9.3-p545
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24 revision 45159) [x86_64-linux]
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24 revision 45159) [x86_64-linux]
Checking revision of all supported applications
Checking revision of httpapi on 10.30.1.1
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
The running revision is not the same as the installed, please restart all applications
/home/gonace/Development/tulo-deployment/lib/capistrano/tasks/revision.rake:20:in `rescue in block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/gonace/Development/tulo-deployment/lib/capistrano/tasks/revision.rake:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/gonace/Development/tulo-deployment/lib/capistrano/tasks/revision.rake:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/gonace/Development/tulo-deployment/lib/capistrano/tasks/revision.rake:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
The running revision is not the same as the installed, please restart all applications
/home/gonace/Development/tulo-deployment/lib/capistrano/tasks/revision.rake:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/gonace/Development/tulo-deployment/lib/capistrano/tasks/revision.rake:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/gonace/Development/tulo-deployment/lib/capistrano/tasks/revision.rake:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => revision:httpapi
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the code you are trying. Otherwise, you are essentially asking someone to write Capistrano output documentation for you, which partially exists here: https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit#output-handling

Comment: Of course, I was not able to access that part when I wrote the question, but I've added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good example of a similar problem being solved in core is here: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake#L91

Along those lines, you'll probably want code something like this:

```
task :httpapi do
  on roles(:httpapi), in: :sequence do |host|
    puts "Checking revision of httpapi on #{host}"
    response = capture "curl -L 'http://#{fetch(:diagnostics_username)}:#{fetch(:diagnostics_password)}@#{host}/diagnostics/status?mode=extended&output=detailed'"
    object = JSON.parse(response, object_class: OpenStruct)

    unless object.result.revision == "" #For test, just compare to empty string so error is thrown
      error 'The running revision is not the same as the installed, please restart all applications'
      exit 1
    end
  end
end
```

Edit:

In order to output the colorized text, you can use:

```
Airbrussh::Colors.green('Your message')
```

From: https://github.com/mattbrictson/airbrussh/blob/master/lib/airbrussh/colors.rb

Comment: That seems to get things working but the output is just white plain text, what have I missed?

Comment: Colored text is usually just a part of command output. Is there another example of this in other output that you are trying to replicate?

Comment: Hi as of now if the task exists with an error the text is just plain white, and showing errors as that could easily be missed.

I'm only trying to get the task to show the same output as an Capistrano "execute", so if I change "capture" to "execute" the output changes. However I need to capture the output of the curl command.

Any ideas?

Comment: As well it seems that the task is set to "success" even though it raises an error. So in the output the taks is shown with green text and a "✔" sign.

Comment: Ah. All of the logic to colorize the output applies specifically to commands from SSHKit, not from internal Capistrano commands: https://github.com/mattbrictson/airbrussh/blob/master/lib/airbrussh/command_formatter.rb#L79 However using Airbrussh, there is a probably another way. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Oh I see, I just created a script to run on the local machines, seemed to be the easiest way to get what I wanted.

Thanks for your help :)